# Running Opa server on port 80

Tags: apache, deployment, opa

What would be the cleanest way to run an opa app on port 80 :

- Run the opa app as root ?
- Use iptable to redirect port 8080 to port 80
- run opa app behind an apache server and redirect port 8080 to apache port 80 using ProxyPass ?

Thanks

Kayhman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

- `Authbind` to start your app directly on port 80 via a non-privileged user
- or start the app behind a proxy like `nginx` or `haproxy`.

Answer (score 2):

Option 3: use a reverse proxy such as nginx (Apache would be overkill here) and leave opa on port 8080.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I do on my apache/vhost server to run an Opa app on just one domain. It requires mod_proxy on your apache server.

1. Run Opa as a non privileged user, on port 8081.
2. Configure the virtualhost within apache as follows:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin me@example.org
     ServerName www.example.com
     ServerAlias example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/domains/example.com/www/htdocs
     ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/www.example.com-error_log
     CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.example.com-access_log common

     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyRequests Off

     <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
     </Proxy>

     ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

This forwards all requests to example.com to the opa server running on port 8081.